# Failed to compile values file. ERROR : app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I try to run my program but I have a Build: failed

```
Failed to compile values file
```

I don't know why but the sentence is showing me

```
Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

and I have this error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

and the explanation

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

Does anyone have a solution?
Please?

Answer (score -1):

The error suggests something related to any values file entry you have.
For example : when adding a string entry value many times the char `'` is present without the proper escape char `\`

```
<string name="_title">Today's</string>
```

needs to be corrected to:

```
<string name="_title">Today\'s</string>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's similar to my debug code